# Question about laws of conservation in electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism

One way of deriving laws of energy, impulse and angular momentum of electromagnetic field conservation is following:

1. Introduce two values below:
   $$
   \mathbf P = \frac{c}{4 \pi}[\mathbf E \times \mathbf B], \quad W = \frac{1}{8 \pi}(\mathbf E^{2} + \mathbf B^{2}).
   $$
2. Using Maxwell's equations and time derivative of these values, get the laws.

But how to argue an introduce of values from it. 1? Can Noether's theorem help to argue it?

Comment: These quantities are the symmetrized energy momentum tensor derived by the modification of Noether's argument which gives the correct linear momentum/angular-momentum relationship, but yes, in principle you use Noether's theorem. There was a similar question a few days ago in nonabelian gauge theory: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31941/noether-current-for-the-yang-mills-higgs-lagrangian/31952#31952 . The simple answer is differentiate with respect to $g_{\mu\nu}$, but to fix the Noether prescription to get the same requires an elaborate discussion.