# Why is this stress-energy tensor from Peskin and Schroeder not conserved?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, fermions, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In paragraph 19.5 Peskin and Schroeder discuss the difference between the canonical energy-momentum tensor $T^{\mu\nu}$ and the symmetric and gauge invariant energy-momentum tensor $\Theta^{\mu\nu}$. Ultimately they state that (I am taking the gauge fields zero here) for fermions the latter reads
$$
\Theta^{\mu\nu} = \frac{i}{2}\bar{\psi}\big(\gamma^{\mu}\partial^{\nu}+\gamma^{\nu}\partial^{\mu}\big)\psi - \eta^{\mu\nu}\bar{\psi}\big(i\gamma^{\rho}\partial_{\rho}-m\big)\psi. \tag{19.150}
$$
Taking the divergence yields $\partial_{\mu}\Theta^{\mu\nu}\neq0$. The last term is zero because it is simply the Lagrangian, which vanishes when imposing the equations of motion. The first term ($\propto \gamma^{\mu}$) also vanishes by simply employing the equations of motion. The second term ($\propto \gamma^{\nu}$) however, does not vanish. 
Instead, one can show that the tensor
$$
\tilde{\Theta}^{\mu\nu} = \frac{i}{4}\Big[\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}\partial^{\nu}\psi+\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\nu}\partial^{\mu}\psi - (\partial^\nu\bar{\psi})\gamma^{\mu}\psi -(\partial^{\mu}\bar{\psi})\gamma^{\nu}\psi \Big]- \eta^{\mu\nu}\bar{\psi}\big(i\gamma^{\rho}\partial_{\rho}-m\big)\psi,
$$
*is* conserved by using the equations of motion.

Hence, my question is: did Peskin and Schroeder make a mistake or am I missing something here?

[I know that similar questions have been asked, for instance [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/147283/derivation-of-correction-to-canonical-stress-energy-tensor-due-to-addition-of-to) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27048/the-derivation-of-the-belinfante-rosenfeld-tensor), but they don't help me solve this problem]

Comment: What are the "three terms" you are talking about (I only see two), and why would the Lagrangian vanish when imposing the equations of motion? $\delta L = 0$ on-shell, not $L=0$!

Comment: @ACuriousMind The Lagrangian is first order so it vanishes upon enforcing the equations of motion. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Ah, you're right. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/348085/50583 might be relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The symmetric [SEM tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) for a Dirac fermion is indeed *not* P&S's guess (19.150) but OP's last formula. The latter agrees e.g. with Ref. 1 and formula (10) in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/191762/2451).

References:

1. A. Bandyopadhyay, [*Improvement of the Stress-Energy Tensor using Spacetime symmetries*](http://research.physics.illinois.edu/Publications/theses/copies/Bandyopadhyay/), PhD thesis (2001); eq. (3.20).

Comment: Yes, textbooks discuss the symmetrization of the SEM tensor by the Belinfante procedure only for the em field (equivalently would be to derive it from the em-gravity coupling, see Dirac's booklet on GR), not for the spinorial ones.

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks for the reference. I am happy to hear that indeed there was something wrong with the SEM tensor as presented in Peskin and Schroeder. However, in research articles I very often encounter it in the form of Peskin and Schroeder (that's why I was asking this question in the first place). For instance, here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.6266 (equation 7). So I guess in some calculations it does not matter which one to take? Do you know perhaps why a lot of authors use this "wrong" SEM tensor?