# Symmetric energy-momentum tensor

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In field theory, there's no guarantee that the energy-momentum tensor resulting from Noether's theorem is symmetric. The usual trick to construct a symmetric tensor is to add to the original energy-momentum tensor, the derivative of a function of fields that has three upper indices, and which is anti-symmetric in its first two indices, since the resulting tensor will be conserved.

My question is, although this is a guaranteed way to get a new conserved tensor, but is there a proof in the general case, that there exists at least one function of these functions that we added their derivative, that will make the new energy-momentum tensor symmetric?

Comment: Are you aware that the [Hilbert energy-momentum tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress–energy_tensor#Hilbert_stress–energy_tensor) is guaranteed to be symmetric?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68564/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/270877/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @G.Smith
Yes I am. However, I want the general case, and the Hilbert energy-momentum tensor is not useful with fermions, since spinor fields cause problems in this case.

Comment: @Qmechanic
Thank you, it seems that the links you provided may contain what I am looking for. I will take a thorough look at them ASAP.