# Noether's Theorem for Non-Rigid Transformation

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, field-theory, noethers-theorem

I am reading the yellow book *Conformal Field Theory* by Francesco et al, and am deeply confused by the authors' derivation of the current associated with symmetry transformations (pages 40-41). This is described in [another SE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122965/222821).

Keeping $O(\omega)$ terms (**without any integration by parts**), we can show that

$$
S' = S + \int d^dx \, \omega_a f_a 
    - \int d^dx \, (\partial_\mu \omega_a) j_a^\mu
$$

where $j_a^\mu$ is the current, given by eq (2.141) (I have verified it), and $f_a$ is some weird quantity found to be (hope that there is no mistake)

$$
\begin{aligned}
    f_a &\equiv
    \mathcal{L} \, \partial_\mu 
    \frac{\partial x'^\mu}{\partial \omega_a}
    + \frac{\partial F}{\partial \omega_a}
    \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi}
    \\ &\quad
    + 
    \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu \phi)} 
    \left[
        \partial_\mu \frac{\partial F}{\partial \omega_a}
        - (\partial_\nu \phi) \, 
        \partial_\mu 
        \frac{\partial x'^{\nu}}{\partial \omega_a}
    \right]
\end{aligned}
$$

In the [first answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/322030/222821)  (and also in the book) where global uniform transformation is considered, I understand their argument that $f_a$ should vanish identically (in that answer, $f_a$ is denoted by $[...]_2$). But it seems that this statement is not trivial to understand:

(*Edit*: According to @Qmechanic, the scaling symmetry holds in $d = 2$ only; but I think it does not prevent us to consider it as an example)

For example consider the infinitesimal uniform scaling for scalar fields (here we have only one controlling parameter $\omega$, which is the same everywhere)

$$
x' = (1 + \omega) x
\qquad
\phi'(x') = F(\phi(x),\omega) = \phi(x)
$$

Then obviously

$$
\frac{\partial x'^\nu}{\partial \omega} = x^\nu
\qquad
\frac{\partial F}{\partial \omega} = 0 
$$

By direct calculation, we find

$$
    \begin{aligned}
        f &=
        \mathcal{L} \, \partial_\mu x^\mu
        + 
        \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu \phi)} 
        \left[
            - (\partial_\nu \phi) \, 
            \partial_\mu x^\nu
        \right]
        \\
        &= \mathcal{L} \times d
        - \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu \phi)} \partial_\mu \phi
    \end{aligned}
$$

where $d$ is the spacetime dimension. It does not look like zero at all.

**So my question is**: Is there any *concrete example* supporting that $f_a$ vanishes identically? (instead of just give some vague "physical argument")

Comment: Comments to the post (v1): OP's dilation transformation is not a symmetry of the action for  $d\neq 2$. For $d=2$ the $f$-function vanishes.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122965/2451

Comment: I have edited the question; seek some concrete example instead of vague physical arguments

Comment: A list of examples has non-unique answers. Phys.SE is designed for unique answers.