# Deriving conserved currents by promoting parameter

Tags: string-theory, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, conservation-laws, noethers-theorem

I currently reading [Tong's text on String Theory](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string/string.pdf).

In Chapter 4.1.1 he alludes to a technique to derive conserved currents

> Recall that we can usually derive conserved
>   currents by promoting the constant parameter $\epsilon$ that appears in the symmetry to a
>   function of the spacetime coordinates.

Since I don't know what he refers to, could someone provide me a proper reference?

Answer (score 1):

Tong is alluding to the standard trick in the derivation of [Noether's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) by promoting the (infinitesimal) $x$-independent parameter $\epsilon$ to become $x$-dependent, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/99853/2451) Phys.SE post.