# Variation of the Action under infinitesimal arbitrary transformations and Noether's Theorem

Tags: conservation-laws, symmetry, field-theory, noethers-theorem, classical-field-theory

Let's consider an arbitrary infinitesimal transformation of the fields and their coordinates :

$$x'^{\mu}= x^{\mu} + \delta x^{\mu} = x^{\mu} + \frac{\delta x^{\mu}}{\delta{\omega}^a}{\omega}^a\tag{1}$$

$${\Phi}'(x') = {\Phi}(x) + \delta\Phi= {\Phi}(x) + \frac{\delta\Phi}{\delta\omega^a}{\omega}^a\tag{2}$$

where ${\{\omega}^a\}$ is a set of infinitesimal parameters.
The corresponding variation of the Action is:

$$\delta S= \delta (\int{dx \,\mathcal{L}[\Phi,\partial^{\mu}\Phi]})=\int{(dx \, \delta \mathcal{L}} +\mathcal{L}\,\delta dx)= \int{dx (\delta \mathcal{L}+\mathcal{L}\,\partial_{\mu}\delta x^{\mu})}\tag{3}$$

Now if

$$\delta=\delta_0 + \delta x^{\mu}\partial_{\mu},\tag{4}$$

where:

$\delta_0 \phi (x)=\phi'(x)-\phi(x)$ at first order, then the variation becomes:

$$\delta S=\int{dx\,(\delta\mathcal{L}+\mathcal{L}\,\partial_{\mu}\delta x^{\mu})}=\int{dx(\delta_0\mathcal{L}+\delta x^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\mathcal{L}+\mathcal{L}\,\partial_{\mu}\delta x^{\mu})}$$ $$=\int{dx\,(\delta_0\mathcal{L}+ \partial_\mu(\mathcal{L}\delta x^{\mu}))}=\int{dx\,(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial{\Phi}}\delta_0\Phi}+\frac{\partial{\mathcal{L}}}{\partial[\partial_\mu\Phi]}\delta_0\partial_\mu\Phi+ \partial_\mu(\mathcal{L}\delta x^{\mu})).\tag{5}$$

Using the Euler-Lagrange equations and commuting $\delta_0$ and $\partial$, the last integral becomes:

$$\delta S=\int{dx\,\partial_\mu(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial[\partial_\mu\Phi]}\delta_0\Phi+\mathcal{L}\delta x^\mu)}.\tag{6}$$

Now we go back to $\delta$ from $\delta_0$:

$$\delta S =\int{dx\,\partial_\mu(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial[\partial_\mu\Phi]}\delta\Phi-\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial[\partial_\mu\Phi]}\delta x^\nu\partial_\nu\Phi+\mathcal{L}\delta x^\mu)}\tag{7}$$

and finally:

$$\delta S =\int{dx\,\partial_\mu(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial[\partial_\mu\Phi]}\delta\Phi-\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial[\partial_\mu\Phi]}\delta x^\nu\partial_\nu\Phi+\mathcal{L}\delta x^\mu)}
\\
=\int{dx\,\partial_\mu[\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial[\partial_\mu\Phi]}\delta\Phi+(\mathcal{L}\delta^\mu_\nu-\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial[\partial_\mu\Phi]}\partial_\nu\Phi)\delta x^\nu]}\\
=\int{dx\,\partial_\mu\{[\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial[\partial_\mu\Phi]}\frac{\delta\Phi}{\delta\omega^a}+(\mathcal{L}\delta^\mu_\nu-\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial[\partial_\mu\Phi]}\partial_\nu\Phi)\frac{\delta x^\nu}{\delta\omega^a}]\delta\omega^a\}}.\tag{8}$$

Now defining:

$$j^{a\mu} = (\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial[\partial_\mu\Phi]}\partial_\nu\Phi-\mathcal{L}\delta^\mu_\nu)\frac{\delta x^\nu}{\delta\omega^a} - \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial[\partial_\mu\Phi]}\frac{\delta\Phi}{\delta\omega^a}\tag{9} $$

we eventually get:

$$\delta S = - \int{dx\,\partial_\mu(j^{a\mu}\delta\omega^a)}.\tag{10}$$

Let's suppose for now that $\{\omega^a\}$ are $x$-independent, such that:

$$\delta S = - \int{dx\,\partial_\mu(j^{a\mu})\delta\omega^a}.\tag{11}$$

1. Here's my first question: do I need to ask that $S$ is invariant under my transformations in order to get 
   $$\partial_\mu\,j^{a\mu}=0~?\tag{12}$$
   Or can the transformation be arbitrary given that in every case 
   $$\delta S = 0\tag{13}$$ for all infinitesimal variations of the fields satisfying Euler-Lagrange dynamical equations?
2. Then it comes my second question. My book$^{(1)}$ says that, even not taking EL equations into account, the variation of the action under infinitesimal arbitrary transformation $(1),(2)$ is:
   $$\delta S=-\int{dx\,j^{\mu a}\partial_{\mu}\omega^a}\tag{14}.$$
   Now I don't know how $(14)$ could be derived without taking EL equations into account beacause if $j^{\mu a}$ does not have $\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\Phi}$ terms is just thanks to those equations.

$^{(1)}$Philippe Di Francesco, Pierre Mathieu, David Sénéchal - Conformal Field Theory, page 41.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP asks good technical questions about the proof of [Noether's first theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem).

1. Yes, eqs. (10) and (11) indeed hold on-shell for $x$-dependent ($x$-independent) infinitesimal parameters, respectively, *without* assuming that the action $S$ is a [quasi-symmetry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/11317/2451).

   But there is no free lunch. Without assuming that the action $S$ is a quasi-symmetry, one can *not* conclude an on-shell conservation law (12) from eq. (11).

   The point is that on-shell the infinitesimal variations $\delta S$ and infinitesimal vertical variations $\delta_0 S$ are *not* necessarily zero, but could contain boundary terms. This is because the Noether variations do *not* necessarily satisfy the boundary conditions that we usually impose when deriving the Euler-Lagrange (EL) eqs.
2. Eq. (14) is valid off-shell (modulo boundary terms) for $x$-dependent infinitesimal parameters (with the implicit understanding that the Noether current entering eq. (14) is in general the *full* Noether current rather than the *bare* Noether current (9)). For the derivation of eq. (14) and the trick of how to derive the Noether current via $x$-dependent infinitesimal parameters, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/99853/2451) Phys.SE post. Specifically, the disappearance of the $\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\Phi}$-term is an indirect consequence of the assumption that the action $S$ is a quasi-symmetry.

Comment: Is this because when deriving Euler-Lagrange equations we use only variations of the field and not of the coordinates? So it would be $\delta_0 S =0$ for $all$ infinitesimal transformations of the fields satisfying EL equations. Right?

Comment: Oh sorry! You're right, we impose vanishing variations of the fields on the boundaries in order to get EL equations. But I do have now another question. I'm editing my question

Comment: At the end of the linked Phys.SE post equations of motion are taken into account, so is $(14)$ not valid off-shell?

Comment: The parts of the linked eqs. that are not written with a $\approx$ symbol are valid off-shell.

Comment: So $(10)$ and $(11)$ are valid on shell without assuming quasi-symmetry, while $(14)$ is valid off shell but assuming quasi-symmetry?

Comment: Yes, modulo boundary terms.

Comment: You say $j^{a\mu}$ in $(14)$ is the full Noether current, but the cited book gives the same definition I gave in $(9)$.

Comment: For a general quasi-symmetry, it should be the full NC. Di Francesco et. al. only consider strict symmetry where full NC = bare NC.