# Masslessness of Goldstone modes

Tags: symmetry, field-theory, noethers-theorem

Suppose we have a $G$-invariant action $S$ of a field $\phi$, where $G$ is a Lie group; let then exist a non-zero value $v$ of $\langle\phi\rangle$ such that the $G$-symmetry of the action is broken, and now $S$ is invariant only under the transformations of a subgroup $H$.
As J. Zinn-Justin states in his book *Quantum Field Theory and Critical Phenomena* (at page 324 in the fourth edition), we could approximate the field $\phi(x)$ as $v+\rho(x)+\xi(x) t^av$, where

- $t^a$ are the generators of $G$ which are not generators of $H$,
- $\rho$ is a vector orthogonal to all $t^av$,
- $\xi^a$ are some real coefficients,

The author then says that when this expression is substituted it in $S$, the $\xi$ fields will appear only in the derivatives, since the other terms in the action are $G$-invariant.
Therefore the $\xi$ field, which corresponds to the Goldstone modes of the  theory, has no mass since a $\xi^2$ term is missing in the action.

But I thought $S$ was *not* $G$-invariant anymore, since we broke the symmetry by expanding around $v$? Why does he say this?
Furthermore, why doesn't this reasoning apply to the derivative terms as well? Those were $G$-invariant in $S$, too, so why is the term with the derivative of $\xi$ allowed to be non-zero?

Comment: The question in title and main body (v2) seem different. Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/99853/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $G$ symmetry is a *global* symmetry: the action is invariant only under transformations in which the $\xi$'s are $x$-independent constants.  Therefore the change in $S$ due to the change in $\phi(x)$ away from any chosen value $v$ can be non-zero, but can only involve the deviation of $\xi$ away from constants -- i.e. the derivatives of $\xi$.

I don't inderstand your remark about $S$ being no longer $G$ invariant.  Choosing a value $\phi=v$ does not spoil $G$ invaraianceof $S[\phi]$. It is only the *difference*   $\Delta S[\chi]= S[v+\chi]-S[v]$ that is no longer $G$ invariant.