# Variation of action in terms of energy-momentum tensor

Tags: symmetry, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, noethers-theorem

In Di Francesco, Mathieu, and Sénéchanl, Conformal Field theory section 4.2.2 it is stated that under an arbitrary diffeomorphism $x\rightarrow x+\epsilon$ the action transforms like
$$\delta S=\int d^dx T^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu \epsilon_\nu\tag{4.34}$$
even for fields that do not satisfy the equations of motion. I don't get this. I get that via Noether's theorem
$$\delta S=\int d^dx \partial_\mu(T^{\mu\nu} \epsilon_\nu)$$
for all fields. Then, if the theory has translation symmetry and the field equations are satisfied, we obtain $\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0$, which immediately leads to the first equation. However, my argument requires the use of the equations of motion. I believe I am overlooking something extremely simple. I would appreciate if anyone can point this out to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The energy momenum tensor is *defined* by
$$
\delta S[\phi, g_{\mu\nu}]= \frac 12 \int d^dx \sqrt{g} T^{\mu\nu}\delta g_{\mu\nu}.
$$
In this variation we vary the geometry but keep the fields $\phi(x)$ fixed.
If we start in flat space where $g_{\mu\nu}=\delta_{\mu\nu}$ and make a diffeomorphism  then $\delta g_{\mu\nu}= \partial_\mu \epsilon_\nu+ \partial_\nu\epsilon_\mu$ so
$$
\delta S[\phi, g] = \frac 12 \int d^dx T^{\mu\nu}(\partial_\mu \epsilon_\nu+ \partial_\nu\epsilon_\mu).
$$
No equations of motion are needed, but 
again the fields are to be *unchanged*.
 What does need the fields to obey their  EofM is conservation 
$$
\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0.
$$
This is because the action is unchanged a under a coordinate chage $x\to x+\epsilon$. A coordinate change  requires that    we change both $g_{\mu\nu}$ *and*  $\phi(x) \to \phi(x+\epsilon)$. If the change in $\phi$ is to have no effect on $S[\phi,g]$ then we must require the field to satsify its EofM.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I understand that the claim is true if one uses the energy momentum tensor as defined in your solution. However, the book claims this for the Belifante extension of the canonical energy momentum tensor (see footnote in page 101). Although it is symmetric it doesn't have to agree with the one you used. Moreover, it used this formula to inspire the definition of the energy momentum tensor by coupling the theory to gravity.

Comment: The Belinfante tensor *is* the same one as the hilbert tensor that  I defined. See the derivation of the equivalence in the Wikipedia article on Belinfante Rosenfeld.

Comment: You are right! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, if one reads Ref. 1, then eq. (4.34) refers to eq. (2.191), which in turn refers to eq. (2.142), or better 
$$\delta S~=~ -\int \! d^d x~j^{\mu} \partial_{\mu}\omega_a \tag{2.140}.$$ Eq. (2.140) follows directly from [Noether's first theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem), cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/99853/2451) Phys.SE post, which means that the Noether current is the [canonical SEM tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor#Canonical_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor). In footnotes 2 & 6 it is explained that we can improve the canonical SEM tensor into a symmetric SEM, cf. [Belinfante et al](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belinfante%E2%80%93Rosenfeld_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor), in a way so that eq. (4.34) still holds with the symmetric SEM tensor (up to possibly boundary terms).

References:

1. P. Di Francesco, P. Mathieu and D. Senechal, *CFT,* 1997; Subsection 4.2.2.