# Variation of the Lagrangian and the Noether current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, field-theory, noethers-theorem

In Schwartz’s book, QFT and Standard Model, section 8.3.1, he writes

> if we then let $\alpha$ be a function of $x$, the transformed $\mathcal L_0$ can only depend on $\partial_\mu \alpha$. Thus, for infinitesimal $\alpha(x)$,
> $$\delta \mathcal{L}_{0}=\left(\partial_{\mu} \alpha\right) J_{\mu}+\mathcal{O}\left(\alpha^{2}\right)\tag{8.58}$$

for the Noether current defined as
$$J_{\mu}=\sum_{n} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial\left(\partial_{\mu} \phi_{n}\right)} \frac{\delta \phi_{n}}{\delta \alpha},\tag{8.57}$$
and that

> in scalar QED, with $A_{\mu}=0, \mathcal{L}_{0}=\left(\partial_{\mu} \phi\right)^{\star}\left(\partial_{\mu} \phi\right)-m^{2} \phi^{\star} \phi$ and
> $$\delta \mathcal{L}_{0}=\left(\partial_{\mu} \alpha\right) J_{\mu}+\left(\partial_{\mu} \alpha\right)^{2} \phi^{\star} \phi\tag{8.59}.$$

My question is, why the variation $\delta\mathcal L_0$ equals to $(\partial_\mu\alpha) J_\mu$ in the first order, and how you could obtain higher order corrections.

Comment: Hi. Is this a homework question? If so, please add the tag homework-and-exercises.

Comment: Also it would be helpful if you actually state a question. It's easiest to identify a question when it is a sentence that ends in a question mark. I've tried to answer what I think your questions are with my answer. But it is not entirely clear if you have a question or if you are just stating that you have no clue if your guess works. Your stated guess happens to be wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [On a trick to derive the Noether current](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/99853/2451)

Answer (score 6):

This answer is going to focus on the concepts behind the equation you wrote down for the current, not the specific $U(1)$ example you give.

#### General variation of Lagrangian

Let's first consider a *general* transformation, parameterized by $\delta \lambda$ (I am intentionally going to save the symbol $\alpha$ for later). If we have $N$ fields $\phi_n$, where $n=1, 2, \cdots, N$, then under this transformation, the fields transform in the following way, to linear order in $\delta \lambda$
\begin{equation}
\delta \phi_n = \frac{\delta \phi_n}{\delta \lambda} \delta \lambda
\end{equation}
Meanwhile, the Lagrangian transforms as
\begin{eqnarray}
\delta \mathcal{L} &=& \sum_n \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi_n}\frac{\delta \phi_n}{\delta \lambda} \delta \lambda + \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \partial_\mu \phi_n} \partial_\mu \left( \frac{\delta \phi_n}{\delta \lambda} \delta \lambda \right) 
\end{eqnarray}
If we wanted to derive the Euler-Lagrange equations, at this stage we would integrate by parts and drop a boundary term on the second term. However, in this answer, we will *not* want to do that. Instead, note that we can use the product rule on the last term (this will come back later)
\begin{equation}
\partial_\mu \left( \frac{\delta \phi_n}{\delta \lambda} \delta \lambda \right) = \partial_\mu \left( \frac{\delta \phi_n}{\delta \lambda} \right) \delta \lambda +   \frac{\delta \phi_n}{\delta \lambda} \partial_\mu \delta \lambda  
\end{equation}

#### A clever derivation of the Noether current

Now, consider a *continuous global symmetry* parameterized by $\alpha$. A global symmetry means (a) that the parameter $\alpha$ does not depend on spacetime (so $\partial_\mu \alpha=0$) -- this is the "global" part, and (b) that $\delta \mathcal{L}=0$ (up to a total derivative$^\star$) under a transformation by $\alpha$ -- this is the "continuous symmetry" part. Note that we did not use the Euler-Lagrange equations to conclude that $\delta \mathcal{L}$ vanishes up to a total derivative. Instead, in this context, $\delta {\mathcal{L}}=0$ follows from the fact that $\alpha$ is associated with a symmetry.

Now, let us *promote* the parameter $\alpha$ of the global symmetry to a *function* $\alpha(x)$. The Lagrangian will generally not be invariant under this transformation. What can we say about the variation of $\mathcal{L}$ under $\alpha(x)$? Well, it must be the case that (up to a total derivative$^\star$) the variation **is proportional to** $\partial_\mu \alpha(x)$, because the variation must vanish when $\partial_\mu \alpha(x)=0$ as a consequence of the global symmetry. Furthermore, by Lorentz invariance, when $\partial_\mu \alpha$ appears in $\mathcal{\delta L}$, it must be contracted with a Lorentz vector. Let's call this vector $J^\mu$ (so far, this is not a current, but you can probably see where this is headed!). In equations, we can express this as
\begin{equation}
\delta \mathcal{L} = J^\mu \partial_\mu \alpha(x)
\end{equation}
Now we can integrate this by parts to get the variation
\begin{equation}
\delta \mathcal{L} = - \partial_\mu J^\mu \alpha(x)
\end{equation}
Now, because $\delta \mathcal{L}=0$ for *any* variation *when the Euler-Lagrange equations are satisfied*, and since $\alpha(x)$ is just a special case of a variation, it must be the case that $\partial_\mu J^\mu = 0$ *when the Euler-Lagrange equations are satisfied.* Thus, we identify $J^\mu$ as the conserved current in Noether's theorem.

---

$^\star$ While it's not important in your $U(1)$ example, so I won't pay much attention to it in this answer, this total derivative term is sometimes important to account for when computing the Noether current.

#### Computing $J^\mu$

As a final step, we can put things together and give the explicit formula for $J^\mu$, using our formula for a general variation $\delta \lambda$. Setting $\delta \lambda=\alpha(x)$, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\delta \mathcal{L} &=& \sum_n \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi_n}\frac{\delta \phi_n}{\delta \alpha(x)}\alpha(x) + \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \partial_\mu \phi_n} \partial_\mu \left[\frac{\delta \phi_n}{\delta \alpha(x)} \alpha(x) \right] \\
&=& (...) \alpha(x) + \sum_n \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \partial_\mu \phi_n} \frac{\delta \phi_n}{\delta \alpha(x)} \partial_\mu \alpha(x)
\end{eqnarray}
the term in brackets $(...)$ multiplying $\alpha(x)$ *must vanish identically* (not using the Euler-Lagrange equations) as a consequence of the global symmetry, because of the general argument we gave above. (You can check that this cancellation happens explicitly in your massive complex scalar field example -- it is a direct consequence of the global $U(1)$ symmetry in that case).

Comparing this expression with the formula $\delta \mathcal{L} =  J^\mu \partial_\mu \alpha(x)$, we identify
\begin{equation}
J^\mu = \sum_n \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \partial_\mu \phi_n} \frac{\delta \phi_n}{\delta \alpha(x)} 
\end{equation}
as desired.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough and insightful answer, it's a shame I can't upvote it. For the second order correction in (8.59), does it also follow from Lorentz invariance? If so, how can we identify this term as (\partial_\mu \alpha)^2 \phi^* \phi?

Comment: @Roland Lorentz invariance would tell you that the second order variation needs to have the form $X^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu \alpha \partial_\nu \alpha$. There's no particular useful property for $X$ I am aware of. It seems like it is just something you can calculate as an exercise in your example.

Answer (score 1):

> $$\mathcal{L}_{0}=\left(\partial_{\mu} \phi\right)^{\star}\left(\partial_{\mu} \phi\right)-m^{2} \phi^{\star} \phi$$

> and

> $$\delta \mathcal{L}_{0}=\left(\partial_{\mu} \alpha\right) J_{\mu}+\left(\partial_{\mu} \alpha\right)^{2} \phi^{\star} \phi\tag{8.59}.$$

> I'm not entirely sure how these two equations follows, my best guess is that one can identify $\left(\partial_{\mu} \alpha\right) J_{\mu}$ as $\delta \alpha$...

No, $\left(\partial_{\mu} \alpha\right) J_{\mu}$ is not $\delta\alpha$; it says in the book and in your post that $\left(\partial_{\mu} \alpha\right) J_{\mu}$ is the first order transformation of the Lagrange density ($\delta\mathcal L_0$).

Regarding the first equation above, it also says in your book that $\mathcal L_0$ is the scalar QED Lagrange density for $A=0$ (or equivalently $e=0$). This is also something you wrote in your post.

Regarding the second equation you asked about, Schwartz is literally just making the following replacement in $\mathcal L_0$
$$
\phi(x) \to e^{-i\alpha(x)}\phi(x)
$$
and expanding the terms out...

Just use the fact that
$$
J_\mu = i\left( \phi\partial_\mu\phi^* - \phi^*\partial_\mu\phi \right)
$$