# Lorentz/rotational invariance parameter doesn't vanish on boundaries

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, noethers-theorem

As I know Stress-Energy tensor is defined as Noether current under arbitrary coordinate transformations $\boldsymbol{x} \rightarrow \boldsymbol{x}+\epsilon(\boldsymbol{x})$.
$$
\delta_\epsilon S=\int_{\mathbb{R}^D}\left[\epsilon_\nu\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \Phi} \partial_\nu \Phi+\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial\left(\partial_\mu \Phi\right)} \partial_\mu \partial_\nu \Phi\right)+\partial_\mu \epsilon_\nu \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial\left(\partial_\mu \Phi\right)} \partial_\nu \Phi\right] d^D \boldsymbol{x}.
$$
First term here equals to $\epsilon_\nu \partial_\mu\left(\delta_{\mu \nu} \mathcal{L}\right)$ as a reflection of the fact that the action does not depend on $\boldsymbol{x}$ explicitly and hence for constant $\epsilon_\mu$ the variation should vanish. After integrating by parts we get
$$
\delta_\epsilon S=\int_{\mathbb{R}^D} \partial_\mu \epsilon_\nu\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial\left(\partial_\mu \Phi\right)} \partial_\nu \Phi-\delta_{\mu \nu} \mathcal{L}\right) d^D \boldsymbol{x} \stackrel{\text { def }}{=} \int_{\mathbb{R}^D} \partial_\mu \epsilon_\nu T_{\mu \nu} d^D \boldsymbol{x}=-\int_{\mathbb{R}^D} \epsilon_\nu \partial_\mu T_{\mu \nu} d^D \boldsymbol{x} .
$$
That's where we are getting the definition of SE tensor as a response to the infinitesimal coordinate change
$$
\delta_\epsilon S=\int_{\mathbb{R}^D} \partial_\mu \epsilon_\nu T_{\mu \nu} d^D \boldsymbol{x};\quad \partial_\mu T_{\mu \nu}=0;\tag{7}
$$
So for integration by parts we used the fact that on boundaries $\epsilon(\boldsymbol{x})$ equals 0. But for special case with rotational invarience my teacher writes:

> In $SO(D)$ invariant theories $T_{\mu \nu}$ can always be made
> symmetric. It can be seen as follows. Consider
> $\epsilon_\nu=\omega_{\nu \lambda} x_\lambda$, where $\omega_{\mu
>  \nu}=-\omega_{\nu \mu}$, then from (7) we have $$ \delta_\epsilon
>  S=\frac{1}{2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^D}\left[\partial_\mu \omega_{\nu
>  \lambda}\left(x_\lambda T_{\mu \nu}-x_\nu T_{\mu
>  \lambda}\right)-\omega_{\mu \nu}\left(T_{\mu \nu}-T_{\nu
>  \mu}\right)\right] d^D \boldsymbol{x} . $$ For constant $\omega_{\mu
>  \nu}$ this variation should vanish for rotationally invariant
> theories, which implies $$ T_{\mu \nu}-T_{\nu \mu}=\partial_\lambda
>  f_{\lambda \mu \nu}, \quad f_{\lambda \mu \nu}=-f_{\lambda \nu \mu} .
>  $$

So we demand $\omega$ to be constant which, for ex. in $D=(1,3)$ spacetime definitely means that $\epsilon(x)$ will not vanish on edges of integration and all mentioned theory before will not work because we no more can integrate by parts without getting additional term:
$$\int\epsilon_\nu \partial_\mu\left(\delta_{\mu \nu} \mathcal{L}\right)d^Dx=$$
$$=\int\partial_\mu\left[\epsilon_\nu\left(\delta_{\mu \nu} \mathcal{L}\right)\right]d^Dx-\int\left(\delta_{\mu \nu} \mathcal{L}\right)\partial_\mu\epsilon_\nu d^Dx\neq_{just} -\int\left(\delta_{\mu \nu} \mathcal{L}\right)\partial_\mu\epsilon_\nu d^Dx.$$

Answer (score 0):

1. OP and their teacher are using the [trick of $x$-dependent parameters](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/99853/2451) in [Noether's first theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem).
2. The variation $\delta x^{\mu}~=~\epsilon^{\mu}(x)=\omega^{\mu}{}_{\nu}(x)~x^{\nu}$ is never independent of $x$ for infinitesimal Lorentz transformations; it is instead $\omega^{\mu}{}_{\nu}(x)$ that becomes $x$-independent.
3. OP's calculation is still valid modulo boundary terms.
   For $x$-independent $\omega_{\mu\nu}$, the teacher's formula becomes
   $$ \delta S~\sim~-\frac{1}{2}\omega_{\mu\nu} \int_V\! d^Dx(T^{\mu\nu}-T^{\nu\mu}), \tag{A}$$
   where $\sim$ means equality modulo boundary terms.
4. In fact it is enough to assume that the Lorentz transformation is a [quasi-symmetry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/11317/2451) of the action under Lorentz transformations.
5. From eq. (A) one can infer the existence of the [Belinfante-Rosenfeld SEM tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belinfante%E2%80%93Rosenfeld_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) part $f_{\lambda\mu\nu}$ using arguments laid out between eqs. (9) & (10) in e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/99853/2451) Phys.SE post (i.e. either by assuming an arbitrary integration region $V$, or by using an algebraic Poincare Lemma).

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, how $\omega$ can vanish on boundaries if it's constant

Comment: so $\omega$ becomes zero on the boundaries because of small [buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem#:~:text=continuous%2C%20we%20use-,%22buffering%22,-periods%20of%20small)?

Comment: I updated the answer.