# How to find Belinfante-Rosenfeld SEM tensor?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, noethers-theorem, variational-calculus

Using definition of SE tensor as a response to the infinitesimal coordinate change
$$\delta_{\epsilon} S=\int\partial_{\mu}\epsilon_{\nu}T_{\mu\nu}d^Dx;\quad \partial_{\mu}T_{\mu\nu}=0;\quad (7)$$
We can prove that for $SO(D)$ invariant theories $T_{\mu \nu}$ can always be made
symmetric. It can be seen as follows. Consider
$\epsilon_\nu=\omega_{\nu \lambda} x_\lambda$, where $\omega_{\mu
 \nu}=-\omega_{\nu \mu}$, then from (7) we have $$ \delta_\epsilon
 S=\frac{1}{2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^D}\left[\partial_\mu \omega_{\nu
 \lambda}\left(x_\lambda T_{\mu \nu}-x_\nu T_{\mu
 \lambda}\right)-\omega_{\mu \nu}\left(T_{\mu \nu}-T_{\nu
 \mu}\right)\right] d^D \boldsymbol{x} . $$ For constant $\omega_{\mu
 \nu}$ this variation should vanish for rotationally invariant
theories, which implies $$ T_{\mu \nu}-T_{\nu \mu}=\partial_\lambda
 f_{\lambda \mu \nu}, \quad f_{\lambda \mu \nu}=-f_{\lambda \nu \mu} ,
 \tag{i}$$
cf. my related Phys.SE question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/754327/2451).

We can build [Belinfante-Rosenfeld SEM tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belinfante%E2%80%93Rosenfeld_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) by:
$$
\tilde{T}_{\mu \nu} \stackrel{\text { def }}{=} T_{\mu \nu}-\partial_\lambda B_{\lambda \mu \nu}  \tag{ii}$$  where $$ B_{\lambda \mu \nu}=\frac{1}{2}\left(f_{\lambda \mu \nu}-f_{\mu \lambda \nu}-f_{\nu \lambda \mu}\right) \text {. } \tag{iii}
$$
But nobody actually says how to find this tensor, do I have to just find noether current under rotations or what?

Comment: So normally the stress energy tensor is just defined as the conserved current due to translation not rotation (In flat theories)

Comment: but rotation can be described as local translations that depend of x so my equations don't change

Answer (score 0):

1. Comparing eqs. (i) and (ii) suggests that
   $$ B_{\lambda \mu \nu} -(\mu\leftrightarrow \nu)~=~ -f_{\lambda \mu \nu}.\tag{iv}$$
2. Now eqs. (iii) is an automatic consequence of eqs. (i) and (iv).
3. How to derive the Belinfante-Rosenfeld SEM tensor from the action is discussed in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/195280/2451).

Comment: I am asking how to find particular $B_{\lambda\mu\nu}$ or particular $f_{\lambda\mu\nu}$ for known lagrandian or SE tensor

Comment: I updated the answer.