# Change of action after a transformation with space-time dependent parameters

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, field-theory, action, classical-field-theory

I've been following David Tong's lecture on introduction to [quantum field theory](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html). In his lecture notes page number 19 (and his video class on Youtube), he talks about global transformation that rotates the phase of a complex scalar field $\phi$ but with spacetime dependent variable $\alpha = \alpha(x)$.

If the parameter alpha isn't spacetime dependent, the lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$ is invariant $(\delta \mathcal{L}=0)$, which makes the transformation a symmetry. But if it is spacetime dependent, then the resulting changes would have the form of:
$$ \delta\mathcal{L}=\partial_\mu \alpha(x) h^\mu(\phi) \tag{1.65}$$

He mentions that we can still make the transformation a symmetry as long as the action is invariant $(\delta S =0)$.  Based on (1.65) the change in action is therefore:

\begin{equation}
\delta S=\int d^4x \enspace \delta \mathcal{L} = - \int  d^4x \enspace \alpha(x) \partial_\mu h^\mu\tag{1.66}
\end{equation}

and this is where I'm confused. My attempt to understanding it is here:

\begin{align}
\delta S&=\int d^4x \enspace \delta \mathcal{L}\\
&= \int d^4x \enspace \partial_\mu \alpha(x) h^\mu(\phi)\\
&= \int d^4x \enspace \big[ \partial_\mu(\alpha(x)h^\mu)-\alpha(x)\partial_\mu h^\mu \big]
\end{align}

Can anyone please correct me or tell me why I'm not arriving with the same formulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, OP is right. Tong is suppressing a total derivative term in eq. (1.66). See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/99853/2451) related Phys.SE post.