# Energy-Momentum Tensor in QFT vs. GR

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

What is the correspondence between the conserved canonical energy-momentum tensor, which is $$ T^{\mu\nu}_{can} := \sum_{i=1}^N\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}_{Matter}}{\delta(\partial_\mu f_i)}\partial^\nu f_i - \eta^{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}$$ (the four conserved Noether currents corresponding to four possible spacetime translations)

where $\{f_i\}_{i=1}^N$ are the $N$ matter fields in the theory, and we assume $f_i\mapsto\alpha^\nu\partial_\nu f_i$ for translations,

and stress-energy tensor from the Einstein-Hilbert action, which is: $$ T_{\mu\nu}\equiv-\frac{2}{\sqrt{-g}}\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}_{Matter}}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}} $$

In particular, how do you get that the two are equal (are they?) for Minkowski space, for which there is no variation in the metric?

Comment: Even though you are interested in a case where the metric is fixed, say Minkowski, you should still perform the variation with $g$ free as the metric is a dynamical field (in GR). Then in the final answer you may specify to a particular metric.

Comment: See also discussion in Peskin & Schroeder page 683.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27048/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The question (v2) states: _[...] stress-energy tensor (SET) from the Einstein-Hilbert (EH) action._ Note that the SET in the Einstein field equations (EFE) is typically from a matter action, not from the EH action.

Comment: You may find interesting: https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0208003 and https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0306020.

Comment: Dear Fede LA: Are you in any way related to the author of the two links? For your information, Physics.SE has a [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/582/2451) that it is OK to cite oneself, but it should be stated clearly and explicitly in the answer itself, not in attached links.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should think at the way the Noether current is obtained. When an infinitesimal symmetry transformation is made spacetime dependent, that is the parameters $\omega^a$ that control the symmetry are taken as functions of the spacetime point $\omega^a=\omega^a(x)$, the action is not longer left invariant
$$
\delta S=-\int d^D x\, J^{a\,\mu}(x)\partial_\mu \omega^a(x)
$$
but rather it provides the definition of the current $J^{a\,\mu}$ that is conserved on-shell.

Now, let's look at the case of the energy momentum tensor: in this case, the translations $x^\nu\rightarrow x^\nu+\omega^\nu$ are made local $x^\nu\rightarrow x^\nu+\omega^\nu(x)$ so that 
$$
\delta S=-\int d^D x\, T_\nu^\mu(x)\,\partial_\mu \omega^\nu(x)\,.
$$
Actually, one looks for a symmetric tensor $T^{\mu\nu}=T^{\nu\mu}$ so that one can rewrite the expression above in the following form
$$
\delta S=-\frac{1}{2}\int d^D x\, T^{\nu\mu}(x)\,(\partial_\mu \omega_\nu(x)+\partial_\nu\omega_\mu)\,.
$$
Now, here is the catch: if we were to transform the spacetime metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ (equal to $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ in the case at hand) as if $x^\nu\rightarrow x^\nu+\omega^\nu(x)$ was just an infinitesimal change of coordinates, that is 
$$g_{\mu\nu}\rightarrow g_{\mu\nu}-(\partial_\mu \omega_\nu(x)+\partial_\nu\omega_\mu)\,,$$
then the action (rendered coordinates independent by the inclusion of the metric in the usual way such as $d^D x\rightarrow d^D x \sqrt{|g|}\,,\ldots$) would be left invariant 
$$
\delta S=-\frac{1}{2}\int d^D x\, (\partial_\mu \omega_\nu(x)+\partial_\nu\omega_\mu)\left. \left(\sqrt{|g|}\,T^{\mu\nu}(x)+2\frac{\delta S(x)}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}}\right)\right|_{g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}}=0\,.
$$
From this equation it follows that the current associated with spacetime translations can be written as
$$
T^{\mu\nu}=\left. -\frac{2}{\sqrt{|g|}}\frac{\delta S}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}}\right|_{g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}} \qquad \mbox{evaluated on the bkg }g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}\,.
$$
It should be apparent that this definition gives a symmetric energy-momentum tensor that matches the one appearing the Einstein's equations. From the derivation above it should also be clear that the alternate versions of $T_{\mu\nu}$ arise because the definition of $T^{\mu\nu}$ via the variation of the action when the translation is made spacetime dependent does not uniquely fix it. For example, given a valid $T_{\mu\nu}$, one can always  define another one $T^{\mu\nu}\rightarrow T^{\mu\nu}_B=T^{\mu\nu}+\partial_\rho B^{\rho\mu\nu} $ with an arbitrary $B^{\rho\mu\nu}=-B^{\mu\rho\sigma}$ which also gives
$$
\delta S=-\int d^D x\, T^{\mu\nu}(x)\partial_\mu\omega_\nu(x)=-\int d^D x\, T_B^{\mu\nu}(x)\partial_\mu\omega_\nu(x)
$$
up to an integration by parts. Einstein's equations break this degeneracy and nicely identify ``the'' energy-momentum tensor.

Answer (score 16):

Let there be given a general covariant matter action
$$S~=~ \int \! d^4x~ {\cal L},  \qquad {\cal L}~=~e L, \qquad
L~=~L(\Phi,\nabla_a\Phi). \tag{1}$$

The main strategy will be to demand that the matter fields $\Phi^A$ carry flat rather than curved indices$^1$. This is achieved with the help of a [vielbein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_formalism_%28physics%29) $e^a{}_{\mu}$, where

$$g_{\mu\nu}~=~e^a{}_{\mu} ~\eta_{ab}~e^b{}_{\nu}, \qquad 
e^a{}_{\mu}~ E^{\mu}{}_b~=~\delta^a_b, \qquad  
E^{\mu}{}_a~e^a{}_{\nu}~=~\delta^{\mu}_{\nu}, \tag{2}$$

$$ e~:=~\det(e^a{}_{\mu})~=~\sqrt{|g|}, \tag{3}$$

and a [spin connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_connection) $\omega_{\mu}{}^a{}_b$ compatible with the Levi-Civita [Christoffel symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols) $\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\lambda}$,

$$0~=~(\nabla_{\mu}e)^{a}{}_{\nu}~=~\partial_{\mu}e^{a}{}_{\nu} +\omega_{\mu}{}^a{}_b ~e^b{}_{\nu}- e^a{}_{\lambda}~\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\lambda}.\tag{4}$$

In other words, the spin connection $\omega_{\mu}{}^a{}_b$ is uniquely given by

$$2\omega_{\mu, ab}~=~2\left(-\partial_{\mu}e_{a\nu}
+e_{a\lambda}~\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\lambda}\right)E^{\nu}{}_b
~=~-\left(\partial_{\mu}e_{a\nu}
+\partial_a g_{\mu\nu}\right)E^{\nu}{}_b -(a\leftrightarrow b)$$
$$~=~-\partial_{\mu}e_{a\nu}~E^{\nu}{}_b-\partial_a e_{b\mu} + g_{\mu\nu}~\partial_a E^{\nu}{}_b -(a\leftrightarrow b),\tag{5}$$

$$2\omega_{c, ab}~:=~2E^{\mu}{}_c~\omega_{\mu, ab}
~=~-f_{cab}-f_{abc}-f_{acb}-(a\leftrightarrow b), \tag{6}$$

$$f_{abc}~:=~\partial_a e_{b\nu}~E^{\nu}{}_c . \tag{7}$$

The covariant derivative of the matter fields is of the form

$$ (\nabla_{\mu}-\partial_{\mu})\Phi^A ~=~  \omega_{\mu}{}^{a}{}_{b} ~(\Delta_a{}^b)^A{}_B~\Phi^B.\tag{8}$$

Due to the antisymmetry of the spin connection $\omega_{c, ab}=-\omega_{c, ba}$, it is always possible to write the covariant derivative of the matter fields as
$$ (\nabla_c-\partial_c)\Phi^A
~:=~ E^{\mu}{}_c ~(\nabla_{\mu}-\partial_{\mu})\Phi^A 
~=~ \frac{1}{2}\omega_{c,ab} ~(\Sigma^{ab}\Phi)^A,\tag{9}$$
$$(\Sigma^{ab}\Phi)^A~:=~(\Sigma^{ab})^A{}_B~\Phi^B \tag{10} $$

where $(\Sigma^{ab})^A{}_B$ is a representation of the $so(3,1)$ Lorentz Lie algebra

$$[\Sigma^{ab},\Sigma^{cd}]
~=~ \left(\eta^{bc} \Sigma^{ad} - (a \leftrightarrow b)\right)  
 -(c\leftrightarrow d), \qquad \Sigma^{ab}~=~-\Sigma^{ba}.\tag{11}$$

II) The covariant [Euler-Lagrange equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) for the matter fields $\Phi^A$ read

$$0~\stackrel{m}{\approx}~\frac{\delta S}{\delta \Phi^A}
~=~\frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial \Phi^A} 
-{\cal P}^{\mu}_A \stackrel{\leftarrow}{\nabla_{\mu}} , \qquad
 {\cal P}^{\mu}_A \stackrel{\leftarrow}{\nabla_{\mu}}
~:=~{\cal P}^{\mu}_A \stackrel{\leftarrow}{\partial_{\mu}} -{\cal P}^{\mu}_B~\omega_{\mu,ab}~(\Sigma^{ab})^B{}_A,\qquad \tag{12}$$

where the Lagrangian momenta are

$${\cal P}^{\mu}_A
~:=~\frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial (\partial_{\mu}\Phi)^A}
~=~E^{\mu}{}_a ~{\cal P}^a_A,\qquad 
{\cal P}^a_A~:=~\frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial (\nabla_a\Phi)^A}. \tag{13}$$

[Here the $\stackrel{m}{\approx}$ symbol means equality modulo matter eoms.]

III) The [Belinfante improvement tensor-density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belinfante%E2%80%93Rosenfeld_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) is defined as

$$ 2{\cal B}^{\lambda\mu,\nu}
~:=~{\cal H}^{\lambda,\mu\nu}-{\cal H}^{\mu,\lambda\nu}-{\cal H}^{\nu,\lambda\mu}~=~-(\lambda \leftrightarrow \mu),\tag{14} $$

or inversely

$$ {\cal H}^{\lambda,\mu\nu}~=~{\cal B}^{\lambda\mu,\nu}-{\cal B}^{\lambda\nu,\mu}~=~-(\mu \leftrightarrow \nu),\tag{15}$$

where

$${\cal H}^{\lambda,\mu\nu}~:=~{\cal H}^{\lambda,ab}~E^{\mu}{}_a~E^{\nu}{}_b\qquad 
{\cal H}^{\lambda,ab}~:=~{\cal P}^{\lambda}_A~(\Sigma^{ab}\Phi)^A. \tag{16} $$

IV) The variation of the matter action $S$ wrt. to the vielbein yields

$$\delta S 
~=~\int \! d^4x\left[L~\delta e 
+e\frac{\partial L}{\partial(\nabla_c\Phi)^A}~
\delta (\nabla_c\Phi)^A\right]
~=~\int \! d^4x\left[L~\delta e +{\cal P}^c_A~\delta (\nabla_c\Phi)^A\right]
,\qquad  \tag{17} $$

or,

$$\delta S -\int \! d^4x\left[L~\delta e + {\cal P}^c_A~\delta E^{\mu}{}_c~ \partial_{\mu}\Phi^A\right]
~\stackrel{(17)}{=}~
\frac{1}{2}\int \! d^4x~{\cal P}^c_A~\delta \omega_{c,ab}~(\Sigma^{ab}\Phi)^A$$
$$~\stackrel{(16)}{=}~
\frac{1}{2}\int \! d^4x~{\cal H}^{c,ab}~ \delta \omega_{c,ab}
~\stackrel{(6)+(14)}{=}~\int \! d^4x~{\cal B}^{cb,a}~ \delta f_{cab} $$
$$~=~\int \! d^4x~{\cal B}^{cb}{}_a~ \delta f_c{}^a{}_b
~\stackrel{(7)}{=}~\int \! d^4x~{\cal B}^{\lambda b}{}_a\left[ 
  \partial_{\lambda} e^a{}_{\nu}~\delta E^{\nu}{}_b
+\partial_{\lambda} \delta e^a{}_{\nu}~ E^{\nu}{}_b \right].\tag{18}$$

V) The basic [Hilbert SEM tensor-density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor#Hilbert_stress.E2.80.93energy_tensor)$^2$ is defined as

$${\cal T}^{\mu\nu}~:=~-2\frac{\delta S_m}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}},
\qquad\qquad(\leftarrow\text{Not applicable!})\tag{19}$$

but this formula (19) is not applicable to e.g. fermionic matter in a curved spacetime. Instead the generalized Hilbert SEM tensor-density is defined as

$${\cal T}^{\mu}{}_{\nu}
~:=~-\frac{\delta S}{\delta e^a{}_{\mu}}e^a{}_{\nu}
~=~E^{\mu}{}_a\frac{\delta S}{\delta E^{\nu}{}_a}
~\stackrel{(18)}{=}~\Theta^{\mu}{}_{\nu}+d_{\lambda}{\cal B}^{\lambda\mu}{}_{\nu}, \tag{20}$$

where $\Theta^{\mu}{}_{\nu}$ is the [canonical SEM tensor-density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor#Canonical_stress.E2.80.93energy_tensor)

$$ \Theta^{\mu}{}_{\nu}
~:=~ {\cal P}^{\mu}_A~\partial_{\nu}\Phi^A- \delta^{\mu}_{\nu}{\cal L}.\tag{21} $$

The last expression in eq. (20) is the answer to OP's question about the difference between the Hilbert SEM tensor-density (20) and the canonical SEM tensor-density (21). It is given by the Belinfante improvement tensor-density (14).

IV) The Hilbert SEM tensor-density (20) is symmetric on-shell

$$ {\cal T}^{\mu\nu}~\stackrel{m}{\approx}~{\cal T}^{\nu\mu}, \tag{22} $$

cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/195109/2451), which also explains the connection to Noether's theorems.

Eqs. (15), (20), and (22) imply that the antisymmetric part of the canonical SEM tensor-density (21) is

$$ \Theta^{\mu\nu}-\Theta^{\nu\mu}
~\stackrel{m}{\approx}~d_{\lambda}{\cal H}^{\lambda,\nu\mu}.\tag{23}  $$

References:

1. M.J. Gotay & J.E. Marsden, [*Stress-Energy-Momentum Tensors and the Belinfante-Rosenfeld Formula*](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/%7Emarsden/bib/1992/05-GoMa1992/), [Contemp. Math. 132 (1992) 367](http://www.google.com/search?q=gotay+marsden+1992).
2. M. Forger & H. Römer, *Currents and the Energy-Momentum Tensor in Classical Field Theory: A fresh look at an Old Problem,* Annals Phys. 309 (2004) 306, [arXiv:hep-th/0307199](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0307199).
3. L.B. Szabados, *Quasi-Local Energy-Momentum and Angular Momentum in General Relativity,* [Liv. Rev. Rel. 12 (2009) 4](http://www.livingreviews.org/lrr-2009-4); Section 2.1.1 p. 11.
4. A. Bandyopadhyay, [*Improvement of the Stress-Energy Tensor using Spacetime symmetries*](http://research.physics.illinois.edu/Publications/theses/copies/Bandyopadhyay/), PhD thesis (2001); Chapter 2 & 3.

(Hat tip for Refs. 1 & 2: [David Bar Moshe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/2190/david-bar-moshe). Hat tip for Refs. 3 & 4: [Konstantin Konstantinov](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/64593/konstantin-konstantinov).)

--

$^1$ Conventions: In this answer, we will use $(+,-,-,-)$ Minkowski sign convention.
Greek indices $\mu,\nu,\lambda, \ldots,$ are so-called *curved* indices, while Roman indices $a,b,c, \ldots,$ are so-called *flat* indices. Capital Roman indices $A,B,C, \ldots,$ denote multiple flat or spinorial indices.

$^2$ A [tensor-density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_density) ${\cal T}^{\mu\nu}=e T^{\mu\nu}$ is in this context just a tensor $T^{\mu\nu}$ multiplied with the density $e$.

Comment: More references: 5. L.B. Szabados, _On canonical pseudotensors, Sparling's form and Noether currents,_  [Class. Quantum Gravity 9 (1992) 2521](http://iopscience.iop.org/0264-9381/9/11/017). The preprint pdf file is available [here](http://www.rmki.kfki.hu/~lbszab/doc/sparl11.pdf).

Comment: Another quite comprehensive review https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.01121

Comment: "but this formula (19) is not applicable to e.g. fermionic matter in a curved spacetime"... why not?

Comment: @turbodiesel4598: Because the variation of the metric doesn't capture the variation of the vielbein.

Comment: @Qmechanic ok, I'll have to go read up on that some more, thanks. But what about non-fermionic, non-scalar fields? The Belinfante tensor-density is non-zero for them too, so is (19) also not applicable to them?

Comment: @turbodiesel4598: Eq. (19) is fine if all the appearance of the vielbein $e^a{}_{\mu}$ in the action goes via the appearance of the metric $g_{\mu\nu}=e^a{}_{\mu}\eta_{ab} e^b{}_{\nu}$.

Comment: @Qmechanic So in those cases, the definition in (19) is equivalent to the definition in (20)? If so, then is it correct to say that variation w.r.t. the vielbein is the most general way to yield the EFEs, while variation w.r.t. the metric only works for non-fermionic fields?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi @Evan. Thanks for the feedback. I recorded your suggested edit in v3 so we have it for later. Please note that $d_{\lambda}$ is a total derivative while $\partial_{\lambda}$ is an explicit derivative (unless they act on a fundamental target-space variable where they mean the same).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!