# How the Belinfante term emerges from definition of metrical stress-energy tensor?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, noethers-theorem, variational-calculus

The only place I found this result is equation 2.1.7 in Ref. 1. But I can't worked it out. I have tried to vary the term $\nabla \phi$ respect to $\delta g^{\mu\nu}$ (I am only try in the case of the action functionally depends on $[g,\phi,\nabla \phi]$), but I am not sure how the generators  appeared (the spin tensor contains it), how to swap $\nabla_\mu$ to in front of these terms?

Does anything wrong with that equation?

I guess 'no'. But, if so, how to obtain it?

References:

1. L.B. Szabados, *On canonical pseudotensors, Sparling's form and Noether currents,*  [Class. Quantum Gravity 9 (1992) 2521](http://iopscience.iop.org/0264-9381/9/11/017). The preprint pdf file is available [here](http://www.rmki.kfki.hu/~lbszab/doc/sparl11.pdf).

Comment: The title question (v2) is e.g. proven in my Phys.SE answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/195280/2451).

Comment: Thanks, Qmechanic I guess your answer is right. Equation (8) in your answer     can help me.

Comment: But I wondered that he not use vierbein in his paper at all.