# Integration by parts in general relativity - boundary terms and Stokes theorem

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I am trying to prove that the stress-energy-momentum Hilbert tensor satisfies a conservation law if one assumes diffeomorphism invariance of general relativity.
I have taken the definition of the SEM Hilbert tensor field to be:
$$T^{\mu \nu}=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{-det(g)}}\frac{\delta(\mathcal{L}_{M}\sqrt{-det(g)})}{\delta g_{\mu \nu}}$$
$\delta_{X}S_{M}$ is the variation originating from some difffeomorphism acting on the manifold, which corresponds to some vector field $X$ in $\Gamma(TM)$. 
Following the calculation performed by Uldreth in this comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/394031/202198

I come upon the following expression:

$$ 0=\delta_{X}S_{M} = -\int_{M} T^{\mu \nu} (\nabla_{\partial\mu} X)_{\nu} \sqrt{-det(g)}d^{4}x $$
Now, integrating it by parts, at which I fail miserably, ought to yield something resembling (I think!):

$$ 0 = \delta_{X}S_{M} =  \int_{M}\text{Div(...)} + \int_{M} (\nabla_{\partial\mu} T)^{\mu \nu} X_{\nu}  \sqrt{-det(g)}d^{4}x $$

The rough idea I have is to try to use some covariant Stokes-Gauss law which I cannot really recognise in my situation - and then cross the boundary terms out due to the variation vanishing there.
I am not even sure what should be in the first integral - the divergence of some tensor? Perhaps multiplied by $\sqrt{-detg}$?

Could someone help me work out in detail the steps leading to the final expression? Additionally, but not necessarily, how could one formulate all of the above in coordinate-free notation, where 
the Stokes theorem is much easier to operate with for me?

Comment: The energy momentum does not generally vanish in a diffeomorphism-invariant theory; rather, it is conserved. See e.g. the disucssion around Eq. (5.38) in https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9712019.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right! I must have had in my mind the idea of variation vanishing on the boundary. I have edited the question now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is essentially about integral theorems. So let us see. You have the expression (up to a sign) $$ I=\int T^{\mu\nu}\nabla_\mu X_\nu\ \sqrt{-\det g}d^nx. $$

Utilizing the derivation property of $\nabla$, we can write this as $$ I=\int\nabla_\mu(T^{\mu\nu}X_\nu)\sqrt{-\det g}d^nx-\int \nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu}X_\nu\ \sqrt{-\det g}d^nx. $$

So in the divergence term, you have the divergence of a *vector field*, which is $Y^\mu=T^{\mu\nu}X_\nu$.

The covariant formulation of Gauss' theorem is as follows. Let $\mathcal D$ be a regular domain in the manifold, with boundary $\partial\mathcal D$. Let us denote the coordinates in $M$ with $x$ and the coordinates in $\partial \mathcal D$ by $\xi$. The induced metric is $h_{ij}=(\phi^\ast g)_{ij}$ where $\phi:\partial\mathcal D\rightarrow M$ is the inclusion map.

The Gauss' theorem is $$ \int_{\mathcal D}\nabla_\mu X^\mu\sqrt{-\det g}d^nx=\int_{\partial\mathcal D}n_\mu X^\mu \sqrt{|\det h|}d^{n-1}\xi. $$

Here $n$ is the (usually taken to be) outward-pointing unit normal to the boundary. The boundary's orientation is defined such that if $\{n,e_2,...,e_n\}$ is an *positively oriented* orthonormal basis of $M$ (along $\partial\mathcal D$), then $e_2,...,e_n$ is considered to be a positively oriented orthonormal basis of $\partial\mathcal D$.

Despite the index notation, this is essentially already coordinate free. Let $đ\mu_g$ be the $n$-form on $M$ whose local expression is given by $$ đ\mu_g=\sqrt{-\det g}dx^1\wedge...\wedge dx^n $$ and let $đ\mu_h$ be the $n-1$-form on $\partial \mathcal D$, whose local expression is given by $$ đ\mu_h=\sqrt{|\det h|}d\xi^2\wedge...\wedge d\xi^n. $$

We define for any vector field $X$ the divergence as either $\text{div}X=\text{Tr}\nabla X$ or as $\text{div}(X)đ\mu_g=\mathcal L_Xđ\mu_g$, two expressions, whose equivalence can be readily verified. Then we have $$ \int_\mathcal D \text{div}Xđ\mu_g=\int_{\partial \mathcal D}\langle n,X\rangle đ\mu_h. $$

This result actually follows from the generalized Stokes theorem for differential forms, which is $$ \int_{\mathcal \partial D}\omega=\int_\mathcal D d\omega $$ (where $\omega$ is an $n-1$-form). To see that this does follow from the generalized Stokes theorem, consult *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* by John Lee or *General Relativity* by Straumann. The omitted proofs are also found in these books.

Comment: Thank you for answering in such detail! I suppose I have to familiarise myself with books you recommended.