# How we can deduce from symmetry of $ θ^{μν} $ that total energy-momentum due to field spin is zero?

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, angular-momentum, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I am self-studying the book “James H. Luscombe, Core Principles of Special and General Relativity”. In “CHAPTER 9 : Energy-momentum of fields” of the book, it starts by introducing Noether’s theorem and then shows that invariance under spacetime translations implies conservation of field energy and momentum:
$$T^{μν}≡g^{μν} L-(∂^μ ϕ_α)\frac{∂L}{∂(∂_ν ϕ_α)}$$
$$∂_ν T^{μν}=0$$
in which $T^{μν}$ is canonical energy-momentum tensor,
and then shows that invariance under Lorentz transformations implies conservation of angular momentum current density tensor:
$$J^{ρτμ}≡x^ρ T^{τμ}-x^t T^{ρμ}+ϕ^τ  \frac{∂L}{∂(∂_μ ϕ_ρ )} -ϕ^ρ  \frac{∂L}{(∂(∂_μ ϕ_τ))}$$
$$∂_μ J^{ρτμ}=0.$$
Then the book groups terms of $J^{ρτμ}$ in two part

1. orbital momentum density $L^{ρτμ}=x^ρ T^{τμ}-x^t T^{ρμ}$ and
2. spin density $S^{ρτμ}=\frac{∂L}{∂(∂_μ ϕ_ρ )} -ϕ^ρ\frac{∂L}{(∂(∂_μ ϕ_τ))}$.

Then the book define an equivalent symmetric energy-momentum tensor
$$T^{μν}→θ^{μν}≡T^{μν}+\frac{1}{2} ∂_λ (S^{μλν}+S^{νλμ}-S^{μνλ})$$
to write $J^{ρτμ}$ as
$$J^{ρτμ}→J_θ^{ρτμ}≡x^ρ θ^{τμ}-x^t θ^{ρμ}=J^{ρτμ}+∂_λ (x^ρ ψ^{τλμ}-x^τ ψ^{ρλμ}).$$
Then book states “The symmetric tensor $θ^{μν}$ describes the same total energy-momentum as does $T^{μν}$, implying that the total energy-momentum due to field spin is zero”?

[image]

My question is How we can deduce from symmetry of $θ^{μν}$ that total energy-momentum due to field spin is zero?

Comment: Hint: Use the [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem). Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119838/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27048/2451 and links therein.